# Sharing VPN of my friend

Tags: windows-7, security, vpn

I am using windows 7 on my laptop. I got VPN ID and password from a friend of mine to have access to blocked sites in my country. I wanted to know does my friend know my activity or which site I am visiting?

Answer (score 1):

If that VPN service does not record your activity and you have separate computers then he will not know.

Answer (score 1):

The proper issue is : do you trust in your friend ...???

If you connect to a VPN server, you must know that the provider (your friend or anything that provide a VPN service) can know all your internet traffic.... Even if the VPN connection is encrypted. Because the connection is encrypted only between your PC and the VPN server. Someone can "listen" the traffic after that. The only traffic who is (at the moment) no listenable is the HTTPS traffic, but you have to verify if the web site is trusted or not.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If the service is runned by your friend he can find out what you're doing.

Comment: It is his personal VPN ID n password.. V r using separate computers. He's in other country